# SonarQube Visual Studio 2013 C++ Plugin

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, teamcity, sonarqube

I have the following setup...

- TeamCity 7.1.5
- Visual Studio 2013
- SonarQube 3.7.4
- SonarQube C++ Community plugin 0.9.1

We have a number of Visual Studio C++ solutions / projects. They all process successfully through TeamCity - Compile, Unit Test, Nuget Package generation, etc. I am now trying to add  the Sonar analysis of those project, using the C++ Community plugin.

Now I understand that the plugin itself does not perform any analysis, that must be done separately and the plugin only imports the results. The plugin is successfully able to identify and import all the Source files, I can seem them listed in within the SonarQube dashboard.
The actual build and analysis is done via Visual Studio / Visual C++ compiler using MSBuild. I have enabled Code Analysis via MSBuild and I can see that it is generating a list of issues. However, I cannot get SonarQube to import that list of issues.

For the MSBuild command I am using the following parameters...

```
/t:Build 
/p:Configuration=Debug 
/p:RunCodeAnalysis=True;CodeAnalysisRuleSet=AllRules.ruleset;verbosity=normal 
/filelogger
/flp:verbosity=diagnostic
```

I have confirmed that a MSBuild.log file is being generated and it is finding issues.

The Sonar-Runner steps has the following options...

```
-Dsonar.language=c++ 
-Dsonar.projectKey=MYProject 
-Dsonar.projectName=MYProject 
-Dsonar.projectVersion=0.0.1 
-Dsonar.sources=Src 
-Dsonar.cxx.compiler.reportPath=*.log 
-Dsonar.cxx.compiler.charset=UTF-8 
-Dsonar.exclusions=**/packages/**/* 
-Dsonar.cxx.includeDirectories=Src/Packages "
-Dsonar.cxx.compiler.parser='Visual C++'"
```

I have also tried using `-Dsonar.cxx.compiler.reportPath=MSbuild.log`

The Sonar appears to run fine, but just doesn't pick up the code analysis issues.

Could anyone please suggest what I could be doing wrong, or what else to try.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks & Regards,

RG

Answer (score 0):

try the last version of the [plugin](https://github.com/SonarOpenCommunity/sonar-cxx/releases/tag/cxx-0.9.4) and make sure all compiler related rules are enabled in your profile. And check your compilation build log, if the paths are relative in there you need to pass /FC flag to the [compilation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/027c4t2s.aspx)